# How to restrict the text field to enter only digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I am trying to create a text field for entering dates that accepts only digits. If any one enter any other character, no need to display in the text field and the cursor need to remain in the same position(no need to move to the next character position). If the entered value is a number , then need to show in the text field and need to move the cursor to the next level.
So at last the text field contains only the numbers.

I am using the following code,

```
$("#date").keyup(function(event){

        //var c=(event).keyCode;
        var c= String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        var cval = $(this).val();

        alert("Characters="+c);
        if(isNumber(c))
            $(this).val(cval+c);

        }
```

Advanced Thanks,

VSoft

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you can use input `type` as `number`.

You can do this:

```
$('#date').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
});
```

I think you need **[jQuery Input Mask Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)**

Comment: @user1431849 check the link in my answer, I think you need something like this.

Answer (score 0):

you should run your function only when Focus is on the requested text field

Comment: i mean when the user focus input on your text field you should add function to check user input....$('#yourInput').focus(function() {
  var userInput=$('#yourInput').val();
});